# How can I get data from Firestore document fields in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to test Firestore in my Flutter app, but I can't really load the data as expected.

This is how I get the data:

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection('Test')
        .document('test')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
          // Use ds as a snapshot

          print('Values from db: $ds');
        });
```

And the *print* statement output:

> flutter: Values from db: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'.

I also tried the following, without success:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Test').document('test').get().then((data) {
  // Use ds as a snapshot

  if (data.documentID.length > 0) {
    setState(() {
      stackOver = data.documentID;
      print(stackOver);
    });
  }
});
```

The output here is only the *documentID* name...

So, how could I get the field values from Firestore?

Comment: try using ds["fieldname"] or ds.fieldname

Comment: What fields you have? means what model you have, can you tell me?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Test(Collection) -> test(document) -> stackTest: value(field-ref and value)

Comment: @ParthPatel thanks, it works with your method. :)

Comment: @RusbenWladiskoz It's my pleasure. You can Flag and Upvote my comment :)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
final String _collection = 'collectionName';
final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;

getData() async {
  return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).getDocuments();
}

getData().then((val){
    if(val.documents.length > 0){
        print(val.documents[0].data["field"]);
    }
    else{
        print("Not Found");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem and solved it this way:

```dart
Stream<DocumentSnapshot> provideDocumentFieldStream() {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .document('document')
        .snapshots();
}
```

After that, I used a StreamBuilder to consume the method created above:

```dart
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: provideDocumentFieldStream(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //snapshot -> AsyncSnapshot of DocumentSnapshot
            //snapshot.data -> DocumentSnapshot
            //snapshot.data.data -> Map of fields that you need :)

            Map<String, dynamic> documentFields = snapshot.data.data;
            //TODO Okay, now you can use documentFields (json) as needed

            return Text(documentFields['field_that_i_need']);
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Null safe code:

- One time reading of the data:

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  var docSnapshot = await collection.doc('some_id').get();
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;

    // You can then retrieve the value from the Map like this:
    var name = data['name'];
  }
  ```
- Continually listening for the data:

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  collection.doc('some_id').snapshots().listen((docSnapshot) {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;

      // You can then retrieve the value from the Map like this:
      var name = data['name'];
    }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of users in a Firestore database and I need to extract the userName information:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class Database {
  static String? userName;

  static void showDisplayName() async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    // userUid is the current authenticated user
    var docSnapshot = await collection.doc(userUid).get();

    Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;

    userName = data['displayName'];
  }
}
```

Then you can call `Database.userName` to get the string value

Here is my Firestore example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### There are 2 ways:

#### 1. StreamBuilder

> When you want to listen to changes constantly, and want the data to get updated without hot reload/restart

#### 2. FutureBuilder

> When you want to get the document only once and have no requirement of listening constantly to the change of the document.

---

### StreamBuilder

#### 1. Multiple Documents

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore
                  .instance.
                  .collection('users') //  Your desired collection name here
                  .snapshots(), 
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(data['fullName']), //  Your valid data here
              );
            }).toList());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### 2. Single Document

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream:  FirebaseFirestore
                   .instance
                   .collection('users')
                   .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid) //  Your document id change accordingly
                   .snapshots(), 
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                snapshot.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Text(data['fullName']); //  your valid data here
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

### FutureBuilder

#### 1. Multiple Documents

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection('users') //  Your collection name here
                .get(), 
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['avatar']), //  Your valid data here
            );
          }).toList());
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```

#### 2. Single Document

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)  //  Your document id change accordingly
            .get(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          return Text(data['fullName']); // Your valid data here
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```